# Showing Max Region

Tags: excel

Given that:

```
ATLA  CENT

20    43
```

Which region has the most towns?

Workings:

It's obviously CENT but I'm not sure how to express this

I used

```
=MAX(A2:B2)
```

which gives 43 but I don't how to say "CENT"

Comment: you might want to look at vlookup or hlookup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With data in the first two rows, consider:

```
=INDEX(1:1,MATCH(MAX(2:2),2:2,0))
```

[image]